# create training and testing set with ground truth for Hyper spectral satellite imagery

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, classification, octave

I am trying to create Training and Testing set out of my ground truth(observation) data which are presented in a tif (raster) format.

Actually, I have a hyperspectral image (Satellite image) which has 200 dimensions(channels/bands) along with the corresponding label(17 class) which are stored in another image. Now, my goal is to implement a classification algorithm and then check the accuracy with the testing dataset.

My problem is, that I do not know how can I describe to my algorithm that which pixel belongs to which class and then split them to taring and testing set.

I have provided a face idea of my goal which is as follows:
But I do not want to do this since I have 145 * 145 pixels dim, so it's not easy to define the location of these pixels and manually assign to their corresponding class.

note that the following example is for 3D image and I have 200D image and I have the labels (ground truth) so I do not need to specify them like the following code but I do want to assign them to their pixels member.

```
   % Assigning pixel(by their location)to different groups. 
  tpix=[1309,640 ,1;... % Group 1
        1218,755 ,1;... 
        1351,1409,2;... % Group 2
        673 ,394 ,2;...
        285 ,1762,3;... % Group 3
        177 ,1542,3;...
        538 ,1754,4;... % Group 4
        432 ,1811,4;...
        1417,2010,5;... % Group 5
        163 ,1733,5;...
        652 ,677 ,6;... % Group 6
        864 ,1032,6];

 row=tpix(:,1);   % y-value
 col=tpix(:,2);   % x-value
 group=tpix(:,3); % group number
 ngroup=max(group);

 % create trainingset 
 train=[];

 for i=1:length(group)
  train=[train; r(row(i),col(i)), g(row(i),col(i)), b(row(i),col(i))];
 end %for
```

Comment: I am in the progress of learning it and I love it. 
I have never work which such dataset (hyperspectral data) and this is my very first experience and I have the plan to implement a machine learning algorithm and then give a remote Sensing pipeline to it to process automatically.

Comment: I should modify my question, I guess

Comment: Thank you I will check it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand this right? At the seconlast line the `train` variable gets the values it has until now + the pixels in red, green and blue? Like, you want them to be displayed only in red,green and blue? Only certain ones or all of them? I could imagine that we define an image matrix and then place the values in the images red, green and blue layers. Would that help? I'd make you the code if this is you issue :)

Edit: Solution

```
%download the .mats from the website and put them in folder of script
load 'Indian_pines_corrected.mat'; 
load 'Indian_pines_gt.mat';

ipc = indian_pines_corrected;
gt  = indian_pines_gt;

%initiating cell
train = cell(16,1);

%loop to search class number of the x and y pixel coordinates 
for c = 1:16
    for i = 1:145
        for j = 1:145

            % if the classnumber is equal to the number in the gt pixel, 
            % then place the pixel from ipc(x,y,:) it in the train{classnumber}(x,y,:)  
            if gt(i,j) == c
                train{c}(i,j,:) = ipc(i,j,:);


            end %if
        end %for j
    end %for i
end %for c
```

Now you get the train cell that has a matrix in each cell. Each cell is one class and has only the pixels inside that you want. You can check for yourself if the classes correspond to the shape.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I do not need to create an RGB image out of 200 channels. I have a matrix  145 * 145 (contains the classes numbers) and an image 145* 145 * 200 and I want to overlay them to gather to see which pixel of image is belong to which class stored in the mentioned matrix.

Comment: And the I am willing to spilt it to Training and tesing set

Comment: Okay, I've got an idea of what you want to do. The easiest way to do this is with a mesh. You'll get a 3D image that is composed of 200 diferent `145` x `145` images. So each Group is one image. The way you look at the image is easily manipulated, I can help you with that too if you want. In short I'll get the code up and running. Do you mind if I use random numbers for the x and y values just for the test now?

Comment: Appreciate your help, I would like to share the data which is in the following link. 
It is one of the most famous datasets for hyperspectral sensors. 
the dataset called "Indian Pines"
Link : http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/index.php/Hyperspectral_Remote_Sensing_Scenes#Indian_Pines

Comment: What are you to do with the values of each pixel? Do you have to examine the values to the values of the classes from the table in the link you posted? and if they are in a certain percentage near to that value of the class, the values its accepted? Did I understand this right? And if so, whats the percentage i can use? Value of the pixel accepted in class if +/- 5%? Is that reasonable?

Comment: This that you mentioned is back to the accuracy of the classification. 
The only thing I want is to have each pixel location assigned to its corresponding class in an array or whatever is more simple and then split them to train and test set. that's all, then I will feed it to my algorithm and I check the result by a least squared method. Eventually, I will check the recovered coefficient on test data to check for any ill-posed problem (over/under fitting)

Comment: The thing you want is a bit difficult to understand, sorry. So finding each pixels location is easy for each group. But what do you mean with assigning the pixel value to corresponding class? What class? And how are they defined? Are the Classes you mean in the Table from the "Indian Pines"? Like this:
(#  Class  Samples);
(1  Alfalfa  46);
(2  Corn-notill  1428);
etc.

Comment: Look at my proposal code. 
At the first line, I have created a tpix (training pixels) variable which holds the location of the pixels in the image and the corresponding class. In fact, I told, that I want pixels x and y location to be in class1 and so on. But here in my case, I have the class label which is represented by a 145 * 145 image and I want to only mach the location of the pixels to their class. That is all.

Comment: Look at the edit of the first answer. Hope this is what you want :)

Comment: Hi, Dear many thanks for your effort. I appreciate that. I have found that what I wanted to do was to reshape my image from raster to vector to make it easy to have each band as explanatory variable and labels as my respond variable

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I could solve my problem. The following code reshapes the matrix(Raster) to vector and then I index the Ground Truth data to find the corresponding pixel's location in Hyperspectral image.

Note that I am looking for an efficient way to construct Training and Testing set.

```
GT = indian_pines_gt;
data = indian_pines_corrected;
data_vec=reshape(data, 145*145,200);
GT_vec = reshape(GT,145*145,1);
[GT_vec_sort,idx] = sort(GT_vec);

%INDEXING.
index = find(and(GT_vec_sort>0,GT_vec_sort<=16));
classes_num = GT_vec_sort(index);

%length(index)


for k = 1: length(index)
  classes(k,:) = data_vec(idx(index(k)),:);
end 

figure(1)
plot(GT_vec_sort)
```

## New.

I have done the following for creating Training and Testing set for #Hyperspectral images(Pine dataset). No need to use for loop

```
clear all
load('Indian_pines_corrected.mat');
load Indian_pines_gt.mat;
GT = indian_pines_gt;
data = indian_pines_corrected;

%Convert image from raster to vector. 
data_vec = reshape(data, 145*145, 200);

%Provide location of the desired classes.  
GT_loc = find(and(GT>0,GT<=16));
GT_class = GT(GT_loc)
data_value = data_vec(GT_loc,:)

% explanatories plus Respond variable. 
%[200(variable/channel)+1(labels)= 201])
dat = [data_value, GT_class];

% create random Test and Training set.
[m,n] = size(dat);
P = 0.70 ;
idx = randperm(m);
Train = dat(idx(1:round(P*m)),:); 
Test = dat(idx(round(P*m)+1:end),:);
X_train = Train(:,1:200); y_train = Train(:, 201);
X_test = Test(:,1:200); y_test = Test(:, 201);
```